# User.Identity.Name Returns null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, single-sign-on, identityserver3

My SSO proxy developed by `asp.net core 1.1` and few client applications also developed by core 1.1 it working fine. If I try to implement 4.5.2 developed client app it authenticated successful , but when I try to retrieve user name i faced this issue.

My Code:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
   ClaimsPrincipal icp = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal;
    // Access IClaimsIdentity which contains claims
    ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)icp.Identity;
    Response.Write("User Name:"+ User.Identity.Name + "<br>");
    // Access claims
    foreach (Claim claim in claimsIdentity.Claims)
     {
        Response.Write(claim.Type+"<br>");
        Response.Write(claim.Value + "<br>");
        Response.Write(claim.ValueType + "<br>");
    }
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `User.Identity.GetUserId()` instead of `User.Identity.Name`

Comment: System.Security.Principal only have User.Identity.Name  , not have method  GetUserId()